# How to update local txt/csv file using javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, csv, fetch

I'm trying to write some javascript that first reads a local csv file, updates it and overwriter the original with its new value. Using console.log() I can confirm that I can read the file, but when I try to upload it using POST i get error message 405 'net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method not allowed'. what is wrong?

```
async function getData() {
    var a = performance.now();
    const response = await fetch("runnerDB2.csv");
    const data = await response.text();

    const lines = data.split("\n");
    const CSVData = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        CSVData[i] = lines[i].split(",");
    }
    console.log(CSVData[1][3]);

    CSVData[1][3] = 5;

    console.log(CSVData[1][3]);

    let text = CSVData.toString();

    console.log(text);

    fetch('/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: text,
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'text/plain'}
      });

    var b = performance.now()
    alert('Time for execution: ' + (b-a) + 'ms.');
}
```

[image: console error screendump]

Comment: http 405 = method not allowed

Comment: what kind of technologies are you using for backend ? or what do you mean by "local" ?

Comment: Right now i'm just running a "live server" in VS code. But it is supposed to be published on an apache server on a rpi. The local file is a csv file which is in the same dir as .html and .js and so on. I just need to change the values from a webpage

Comment: It seems the get request against your "server" is currently not allowed. Have you tried it with a local version of a real server?

Comment: You suggests to just upload it on the rpi apache and see if that servers permissions is different?

Comment: On the rpi it returns a promise now in console. So i suppose the live server extentions isn't supporting post...